# Extra markers appearing on google static map

Tags: google-maps, static, markers

Can anyone explain to me why this URL for google static maps also shows a location in France?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
center=USA&
scale=2&
size=1920x360&
maptype=roadmap&
region=us&
markers=size:tiny%7Ccolor:red%7C
label:M%7Cnew+york,ny%7C
label:M%7Cmobile,al%7C&
key=
```

obviously I've removed my key for security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a erroneous marker style that is not at the beginning of the `&markers=` parameter (per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers) those must be at the beginning of the list:

> The set of markerStyles is declared at the beginning of the markers declaration and consists of zero or more style descriptors separated by the pipe character (|), followed by a set of one or more locations also separated by the pipe character (|).

```
label:M%7Cmobile,al%7C&
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/81ndefgr/)

**code snippet:**

```html
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=USA&scale=2&size=1920x360&maptype=roadmap&region=us&markers=size:tiny%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:M%7Cnew+york,ny%7Cmobile,al%7C" />
```